# stm32 cmake linker option for printing float numbers

Tags: cmake, stm32, microcontroller

I have a stm32 project generated by cubemx. When using cubemx generated makefile, I can add the `-u _printf_float` flag to be able to print float values using `sprintf` and the `UART` port.

```
LIBS = -lc -lm -lnosys -lrdimon -u _printf_float
```

I configured my project to use cmake based on [this](https://github.com/prtzl/Embedded_videos/tree/master/046_BUILDING-PT5-cmake/sample-f407vg) repo. There was some errors that I fixed and the project compiles with no errors. My linker options part in the `CMakeLists.txt` file is like below:

```
target_link_options(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE
    -T${MCU_LINKER_SCRIPT}
    ${CPU_PARAMETERS}
    -Wl,-Map=${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.map
    -Wl,--start-group
    -lc
    -lm
    -lnosys
    -lstdc++
    -Wl,--end-group
    -Wl,--print-memory-usage)
```

and `gcc-arm-none-eabi.cmake` file:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX arm-none-eabi-)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT
    "-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections --specs=nano.specs --specs=nosys.specs -specs=rdimon.specs -Wl,--gc-sections")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT
    "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT} -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics")

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}gcc)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER})
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}g++)
set(CMAKE_OBJCOPY ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}objcopy)
set(CMAKE_SIZE ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}size)
set(CMAKE_OBJDUMP ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}objdump)

set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX_ASM ".elf")
set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX_C ".elf")
set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX_CXX ".elf")

set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

after adding `-u _printf_float` to liker option flags in the `CMakeLists.txt` file I got these errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7-m/nofp/librdimon_nano.a(rdimon-syscalls.o): in function `_lseek':
syscalls.c:(.text._lseek+0x0): multiple definition of `_lseek'; /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7-m/nofp/libnosys.a(lseek.o):lseek.c:(.text._lseek+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7-m/nofp/librdimon_nano.a(rdimon-syscalls.o): in function `_close':
syscalls.c:(.text._close+0x0): multiple definition of `_close'; /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7-m/nofp/libnosys.a(close.o):close.c:(.text._close+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7-m/nofp/librdimon_nano.a(rdimon-syscalls.o): in function `_isatty':
syscalls.c:(.text._isatty+0x0): multiple definition of `_isatty'; /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7-m/nofp/libnosys.a(isatty.o):isatty.c:(.text._isatty+0x0): first defined here
```

Is there a way to fix tihs?

Comment: It seems that you have two libraries that define the same functions, hence the linker can't figure out which one to use. Try remove either `librdimon_nano` or `nosys`

Comment: You might have added one of both libraries at the same time as the option. The error message is quite clear on the libraries. Would you mind to remove just the option `-u _printf_float` and try again, please?

Comment: looks like you are missing a C library or a backend at least to the the C library

Comment: @thebusybee removing `-u _printf_float` resolves the errors, but I'm not able to print float values

Comment: @Fra93 if you mean the flags in `gcc-arm-none-eabi.cmake` file, removing only `nosys` has no effect. removing only `rdimon.specs` resolves the errors but another error appears: `usr/lib/gcc .../libm.a(lib_a-wf_sqrt.o): in function 'sqrtf': undefined reference to '__errno'`

Comment: OK, thanks. So it seems as if the linking of the special version of `printf` that supports floats includes references to formerly unreferenced functions like `_lseek()`. Hm. I'm afraid I cannot help further because I don't have your build environment.

Comment: Concerning the library `nosys`, you have it two times, in `LIBS` _and_ in `target_link_options`.

Comment: OK, You're right. `nosys` was causing the problem because it was included in both CMakeLists.txt and gcc-arm-none-eabi.cmake files. I removed `-lnosys` from linker flags in the CMakeLists file. The errors are resolved and float values are printed. Thank you guys.

Comment: You may have found a solution but there is probably an error somewhere else. You have a dupplicate symbols but in two separate libs ``libnosys.a` and `libnosys.a`. This shouldn't be a problem as long as they are in separate archive. Having N times the same lib in a command line isn't a problem as well, try it ! However, I notice something, the `-Wl,--start-group` flag, without a `-Wl,--end-group`. This cause the linker to loop over your lib list and shall only be used when necessary. I doubt you need this.

Comment: @Martin There must have been a mistake in copying the code. The `-Wl, --end` should've been `-Wl, --end-group`. I edited the code.

Comment: So even with the mistake, what justify the use of start-group / end-group for lib c, m, nosys and std++ ?

Comment: @Martin No idea. I'm not an expert in this. But you're right; removing those two lines has no effect on the build results.